# My annonation isn't visible when I add it in the viewDidLoad of my app

Tags: ios, swift, coordinates, archive, cgpoint

I am developing an app where the user has to mark a location on a map, and then save it. My app then archives it, and when the user wants to see that location, the app is supposed to retreive the location's coordinates, and add an annonation on the map if the coordinates exist. Here is the piece of code I created to display the information the user selected-

```
@IBOutlet var mapGestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer!
var item: itemData?

// Item Outlets
@IBOutlet weak var itemInfoView: UIView!
@IBOutlet weak var itemNameTextField: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var itemDescriptionLabel: UITextView!
@IBOutlet weak var mapView: MKMapView!

// Item Location Outlets
@IBOutlet weak var itemLocationView: UIView!
@IBOutlet weak var itemLocationTextView: UITextView!

let dropPin = MKPointAnnotation()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    self.mapView.delegate = self

    // Data loading
    itemNameTextField.delegate = self
    itemDescriptionLabel.delegate = self
    itemLocationTextView.delegate = self

    // Press recognizer

    func mapViewFunc(_ mapView: MKMapView, viewFor annotation: MKAnnotation) -> MKAnnotationView? {

        let annotationView = MKAnnotationView(annotation: annotation, reuseIdentifier: "myAnnotationView")
        // configure the view

        return annotationView
    }

    if let item = item {

        itemNameTextField.text = item.itemName
        itemDescriptionLabel.text = item.itemDescription
        itemLocationTextView.text = item.itemPlace

        dropPin.coordinate = mapView.convert(item.mapPoint, toCoordinateFrom: mapView)
        dropPin.title = "Location of \(item.itemName)"
        mapView.addAnnotation(dropPin)
        print("Set the location of item pin to \(String(describing: dropPin.coordinate))")


    }

    // Styles
    itemInfoView.layer.cornerRadius = 3
    itemInfoView.layer.shadowColor =  UIColor(red:0/255.0, green:0/255.0, blue:0/255.0, alpha: 1.0).cgColor
    itemInfoView.layer.shadowOffset = CGSize(width: 0, height: 1.75)
    itemInfoView.layer.shadowRadius = 1.7
    itemInfoView.layer.shadowOpacity = 0.45

    itemLocationView.layer.cornerRadius = 3
    itemLocationView.layer.shadowColor =  UIColor(red:0/255.0, green:0/255.0, blue:0/255.0, alpha: 1.0).cgColor
    itemLocationView.layer.shadowOffset = CGSize(width: 0, height: 1.75)
    itemLocationView.layer.shadowRadius = 1.7
    itemLocationView.layer.shadowOpacity = 0.45

    }

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()

}
let annotation = MKPointAnnotation()
//let point = mapView.convert(coordinate, toPointTo: overlayView)
func action(gestureRecognizer:UIGestureRecognizer){

    if let item = item {
        dropPin.coordinate = mapView.convert((item.mapPoint), toCoordinateFrom: mapView)
        dropPin.title = "Location of \(item.itemName)"
        mapView.addAnnotation(dropPin)
        print("Set the location of item pin to \(String(describing: dropPin.coordinate))")
    }

    else {
        let itemName = itemNameTextField.text
        let touchPoint = gestureRecognizer.location(in: mapView)
        let newCoordinates = mapView.convert(touchPoint, toCoordinateFrom: mapView)
        annotation.coordinate = newCoordinates
        annotation.title = "Location of \(itemName!)"
        mapView.addAnnotation(annotation)
    }

}

@IBAction func mapLocationPress(_ sender: UILongPressGestureRecognizer) {
        action(gestureRecognizer: mapGestureRecognizer)

}
```

All the print statements I've created work, so I know that the app *does* save the coordinates, and that it *does* convert them properly. However, when the app loads the information in the `if let item = item` portion of the `viewDidLoad`, the pin isn't dropped onto the map like it's supposed to.

Does anybody see why my code isn't working the way it's supposed to? Thanks!

**If you need my full code, tell me, and I will put it into my question.**

Comment: Maybe the map isn't being loaded until after viewDidLoad, have you tried adding the annotation in viewDidAppear or viewWillAppear?

Comment: Also put `func mapViewFunc` out of viewDidLoad

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use

```
func mapView(mapView: MKMapView, viewForAnnotation annotation: MKAnnotation) -> MKAnnotationView? {
        let annotationView = MKAnnotationView(annotation: annotation, reuseIdentifier: "myAnnotationView")
        // configure the view

        return annotationView
}
```

outside your `viewDidLoad()` function

Comment: I moved this function outside of my `viewDidLoad()`, but the pin still doesn't appear when the screen loads, although it  _does_ save the coordinates, and it  _does_ assign the coordinates to the pin. Could it be something else?

Comment: What are you getting here -  `print("Set the location of item pin to \(String(describing: dropPin.coordinate))")`

Comment: When that statement is run, xCode prints `Set the location of the item pin to CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 73.632655333854188, longitude: -104.16040759876424)` (those were the coordinates of the pin that I dropped)

Comment: Did you try to zoom out your map and check whether the annotation is there or not ?

Comment: Whoops. I forgot to look, but yes, the pin _does_ appear on the map, but in the wrong place. That's strange, because now I _also_ realize that the `CLLocationCoordinate2D` coordinate is different than what was saved (which is why the pin is in the wrong place). Why did this happen?

Comment: It will be a better approach to directly save the coordinates rather than saving `_ point: CGPoint` so that you can directly pass the coordinates to your annotation rather than converting the points and showing to the map.

Answer (score 0):

You should put `mapViewFunc` out of `viewDidLoad`, but if you want to leave it in `viewDidLoad`

try

```
func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    DispatchQueue.main.async {
        // add pin
    }
}
```